# SSRS Sorting values alphabetically within multiple columns

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, grouping, multiple-columns

this is my first ever post so please be gentle with me..
I'm a novice SSRS report builder who is trying to achieve something I beleive is so simple, but I can't seem to fathom it.  Any assistance or general points in any direction would be appreciated.

My data looks like this:

```
 ID Measure 1        Barrier 1     Measure 2        Barrier 2    Measure 3      Barrier 3
 01 Replace Lights   Finance       Review Contract  Time         Solar Panels   Finance
 02 Review Contract  Time          Solar Panels     Time         Replace Boiler Finance
 03 Replace Boiler   Disruption    Replace lights   Disruption   Solar Panels   Disruption
```

I need to be able to count how many times **Finance** is a barrier to each measure and how many times **Disruption** is a barrier to each measure and so on...

I think I should group or sort the data in order to apply a count expression but I am not sure of the best way to group or sort the data effectively to be able to render the results in a report.

Thanks in advance

Frustrated novice (aka JMS)

Answer (score 0):

You should give a lot more information, I dont know what version of SQL you are using nor do I know where you get your data (if it is from sql it would be possible to get this data directly in the table from sql.)

In your dataset, add a expression column like this :

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Barrier1.Value = "Finance",1, 0))
```

and name it "Barrier1count"

in your table, right click on the last row, select insert row, outside group, bellow.

under any measure column, do a right click select expression, and paste this

```
=SUM(Fields!Barrier!Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am using SQL2008 R2 and the data is taken from two tables.  I think what you have suggested will require me to create 40 expressions since I have 5 measures and 8 barriers and I need to be able to count all the possible combination of these when they occur? Its a problem with the underlying data in that it comes from optionset fields that are not instrinsic to the records therefore, I am not able to sort, group any of the values easily.

Comment: Nope, what I'm asking is that you create a column for each barrier. In your dataset, right click on it and selected add calculated field (the one that adds a 1 when it sees Finance and 0 when it doesn't). Then on that added row outside of the group you add another expression that shows the sum of the column you created.

Comment: sorry can't edit my old comment so I'm doing a new one. What I'm asking is that you create a column for each barrier. In your dataset, right click on it and selected add calculated field and use the first code I gave assuming barrier1 is the column name of your barrier 1 (the one that adds a 1 when it sees Finance and 0 when it doesn't). Then on that added row outside of the group you add another expression that shows the sum of the column you created the second expression, although there is a typo I should have named it barrier1count so that it uses the new column created.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've created the additional column for barrier 1 for "Finance" as you say and added the sum expression to the report and that counts the number of times Finance appears for Measure1 fine.  What i need to do from here is have a similar field for the other Barriers in Barrier1 i.e. Time, Disruption etc which is why I think I need quite a few expressions to acheive this.  Or is there a way I can count all the instances of Finance and show them on a report as a total alongside the measure whether it is measure1 measure2 or measure3? Really appreaciate your help btw

Comment: Why you just don't do that in sql and populate calculations in ssrs ?

Comment: it's what I sugested at the beggining but he doesn't say what his sources are or if he has access to them... even if it is SSRS you can have different sources than SQL

Comment: For your question yes it is possible, just follow this guide
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d8c31465-bbcb-46c0-9639-5f54345ea363/ssrs-counting-the-number-of-occurrences?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity in my question (as I said I am a newbie).  I am using Visual Studio to build my report, my query has just two related tables ALL of my rows come from 1 table (I need the second table for a parameter field).  I have done as you say and yes it counts all of those instances of Finance, Time etc for Measure 1 but I need it to include all of the instances of Finance, Time etc for Measures 2, 3, 4 and 5.  I need to ensure that all possible combinations are included in the count.  I can't see a way of acheiving this with this solution

Comment: ...and without entering a column expression for each barrier for Measure 2, 3, 4 and 5.  If that is the case then I will have to do that, I just wondered if there was a way of totalling the fields in one go. Its almost as if I need to put the measure and barrier fields into another table before attempting to count all the permutations together (but alas my SQL skills are not up to that)

Comment: I'm going to ask the same question but in a different way to see if it triggers some inspiration.. How do I count duplicate string values **across** a row in the fields Measure 1, measure 2, Measure 3, Measure 4 and Measure 5 where Barrier 1,  Barrier 2, Barrier 3, Barrier 4 or Barrier 5 are equal to "Finance"?

Comment: okay, instead if you have to do a count on all of those what you have to do is add a row outisde of the group, and add this exrpression for barrier 1 =count(iif(Fields!Barrier1.Value='finance',1,nothing))
repeat expression for other columns and add rows outside the group for each element you want to count

Comment: Thanks again Flying Turtle. Once I've added all the calculation expressions for each Barrier type and all the rows for each element how can I count all the figures for the elements together? I presume I would need a sum expression but not sure where I would need to place this?

Comment: you don't need a sum expression, the count takes care of that. just put that expression in a cell outside the group of the table you are working with and it should work fine.

Comment: If you want to try the other way, all you have to do is right click on the left side of the table of the report, and add a new row outside of the group, in the cells of the new row is where you would want to place your sum expression. also, if you're a noobie you could try to download microsoft sql server report builder 3.0 (not 4 because it's for sql 2014) as it's made to do this.